# Using HttpClient with ASMX in C#

Tags: c#, asmx, httpclient

I am playing with `HttpClient'.  I'm wondering if it is compatible with`.asmx` web services.

Say I have a method such as this:

```
        var baseAddress = new Uri("Http://localhost/folder/WebServiceCommand.asmx/");          
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);                      
        var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

        using (var client = new HttpClient(server))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;

            var response = client.GetAsync("GetData").Result;

            Assert.IsTrue(
                        response.IsSuccessStatusCode, 
                        "Actual status code: " + response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Firstly, is what I'm trying to do possible or should I use the older `HttpWebRequest` class?

If it is possible, why is it returning a 404 - NOT FOUND?  If I paste the address into a browser, it is found OK.

Thanks

Comment: HttpClient does not play with SOAP...

Comment: thanks, I feared that was the case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HttpClient with a Web Service ASMX endpoint

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://foo.com/GetVersion");

        var soapXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetVersion xmlns=\"http://foo.com/\" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://foo.com/bar.asmx", new StringContent(soapXml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).Result;

        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```